# Gauss-Green Application on a given integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, greens-function, greens-theorem

I'm trying to solve an application of the Gauss-Green theorem, but I can't find a useful example on my textbook...

The problem asks to calculate and prove the Gauss-Green theorem on the double integral

$ \int\int_{}^{} \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $

in a domain limited by

$ 4 ≤ x^2 + y ^2 ≤ 16 $

$ y ≤ x $

$ y ≤ \frac{x}{\sqrt{3}} $

I really don't know where to start... I only know that the formula to apply is

$ \int\int Qx - Py = \oint  Pdx + Qdy $

and i should consider the given double integeral as the first element of the equation, but how should i proceed to apply and demonstrate Gauss-Green?

Comment: What do you mean? One must prove the Guass-Green theorem for a **vector field** defined over a domain not for an **integral**! I think you mean to calculate that integral using the Guass-Green theorem. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the exercise requires to calculate that double integral and gives the borders of the domain, but I don't even know at what point I should use them...

Sorry for the bad english, not my main language.

Comment: Also, what you have written is the stokes theorem in the plane not the green theorem and it has some errors in it. The stokes theorem is $\int\!\!\!\int\limits_A {\left( {\nabla  \times {\bf{F}}} \right).{\bf{n}}da}  = \int\limits_{\partial A} {{\bf{F}}.d{\bf{r}}} $. When you choose ${\bf{n}} = {\bf{k}}$, i.e., you let $A$ to be in the $xy$ plane then it becomes $\int\!\!\!\int\limits_A {\left( {{{\partial Q} \over {\partial x}} - {{\partial P} \over {\partial y}}} \right)da}  = \int\limits_{\partial A} {Pdx + Qdy} $.

Comment: The theorem i'm supposed to use is:

$ \int\int_{D}^{} (Qx - Py)   dx dy = \int_{d+D}^{} (Pdx + Qdy) $.



It was specified in the exercise itself, the problem is that generally the exercise gives a line integral to convert in a double integral with certain boundaries, and here it gives the double integral, and i don't know how to set the solution...

Comment: See the edited version of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Green-Gauss theorem states

$$\int\!\!\!\int\limits_A {\left( {{{\partial Q} \over {\partial x}} - {{\partial P} \over {\partial y}}} \right)da}  = \int\limits_{\partial A} {Pdx + Qdy} $$

Choose $Q=0$. Then you have

$$\int\!\!\!\int\limits_A { - {{\partial P} \over {\partial y}}da}  = \int\limits_{\partial A} {Pdx} $$

Now in order to relate this to your question, you should find a $P$ such that

$$ - {{\partial P} \over {\partial y}} = {y \over {\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} }}$$

The following $P$ will do this

$$P =  - \sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} \,$$

Now by the green theorem we must have

$$\int\!\!\!\int\limits_A {{y \over {\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} }}da}  = \int\limits_{\partial A} { - \sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} dx} $$
Now, I think your question wants to compute each side of the above equation **directly** and then **verifying** the green theorem for this **special** case. So you must compute a line integral and a double integral for this purpose.

My final hint is to compute these integrals in **polar coordinate** because your $A$ (domain) has a simple representation in polar coordinates

$$\left\{ \matrix{
  2 \le r \le 4 \hfill \cr 
  {\pi  \over 6} \le \theta  \le {\pi  \over 4} \hfill \cr}  \right.$$

I will leave the computation details for you just saying that each of those integrals are equal to $3\left( {\sqrt 3  - \sqrt 2 } \right)$.

Comment: ooh :O i didn't know you could choose a P = 0 or a Q = 0 to integrate only in one variable, that's perfect and very clear, thank you so much!

Comment: Hello again.. i calculated correctly the double integral, but i don't understand why i can't get the same result with the line integral :(.
Given the $ 4 < x^2 + y^2 < 16 $ boundary i'm computing the line integal considering the curves as two circumferences with different radius: $ R1 = 4 $ and $ R2 = 16 $, integrating in $ π/6≤ θ ≤ π/4 $.
Is that correct?

Comment: A simple mistake. $R1=2$ and $R2=4$. :)

Comment: Okay with that parametrisation i'm integrating the first line integral using $ x(t) = 2cos(t); y(t) = 2sin(t) $ and the second using $ x(t) = 4cos(t) ; y(t) = 4sin(t) $. Using the formula $ \int_{dA}^{} F(r(t)) * r'(t) dt $ it returns $ - 0,95 $ which is the exact opposite of the result of the double integral, is it because of an orientation error?

Comment: I don't know since I haven't seen your computation detail. But I have a blind guess. I think you have computed $\int\limits_{\partial A} {  \sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} dx} $ instead of $\int\limits_{\partial A} {  -\sqrt {{x^2} + {y^2}} dx} $

Comment: Considering the previously posted parametrisation, and the formula i wrote in the same post, the rest of my full computation is:

$ \int_{π/6}^{π/4} -\sqrt{4cos^2(t)+4sin^2(t)}*(-2sin(t)+2cos(t)) $

$ + $

$ \int_{π/6}^{π/4} -\sqrt{16cos^2(t)+16sin^2(t)}*(-4sin(t)+4cos(t)) $.

And it returns $-0,16 - 0,72 = -0,95$.
I'm stuck :/

Comment: Your surrounding curve of $A$ has four parts. $r=2$, $r=4$, $\theta  = {\pi  \over 6}$ and $\theta  = {\pi  \over 4}$. You should compute the line integrals over the four parts and then sum it up. Just consider the orientation of the curve must be **counter clock wise**.

Comment: So the two integrals i posted are completely wrong? In which borders should I integrate these four parts?